# Read and excute code from file possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using HTML agility pack in my app to scrape websites. When website is changing, i need to adapt the app to the new html coding. Certifing apps takes some time time that i'm looking for an idea how i can speedup the delivery and provide my own updates.
My question: is there a way for WP to read and execute code from a file in isolated storage?

Comment: I just read about Roslyn for c#, would be nice if this would work for WP...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You should do the parsing on a web server and build an API for your app.